# Jmeter : Websocket Sampler showing error

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, java-websocket

I am trying to connect WebSocket using Jmeter- Websocket sampler.
For this, I used [maciejzaleski](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) plugin.

Getting below error from the `jmeter log`.

> ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory

If I am missing something, let me know how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

As per [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article:

> Check [Project Wiki](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki/Dependencies) for any dependencies, to be completely sure all the jars from target/site/plugins directory should go either to /lib or to /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation. Currently (for release 1.0.1) the required libraries live in [Jetty Bundles 9.1.1.v20140108](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.1.1.v20140108/).

So:

1. Download all required libraries
2. Put them into JMeter classpath (i.e. "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up

Comment: Can you send me the JMeter classpath, I am not getting which libraries should be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below article, I followed and works fine.
By the way take latest Jmeter 3.0 or above.

https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/cloud-based-jmeter-websocket-testing/